# Accounts not supported when using sendfrom zcash cli command for transaction between z-address

Tags: blockchain, zcash

I am looking to perform send funds between z-addresses of zcash
I have tried the following things

- Tried transferring funds between t-addresses. This works perfectly fine.
- Tried sending funds from z and t address using `sendfrom` cli command. This throws the error "accounts are not supported"

Comment: can you provide an example cli command as you're running it (obviously obfuscate the actual addresses you're using).

Comment: i am trying something like this " ./src/zcash-cli sendfrom "ztkS2H7xoS2i1wfjoPWFqSxnN4X8N7BaMA2Z3jevDoZMCDbmNqU2FqH3x7jB24a6FtE3LxJkyAii6heaY1Zuou7ajDJymUQ" "ztcYaGRT4rPfKTR7PPQcNeiZwAwmV34kUSKjUrVGFoPPHb5DwC9dBGL1EE1bqiig3oUgpmzjRr4woVMddNhoUNprRtPwUJB" 1"